# How to join 4 Table to get all 4 tables Data using sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have folow tables

Table_1

```
id  Name     City
1   Mazhar   Banglore
```

Table_2

```
id  College Name      City
1   R K           Banglore
```

Table_3

```
id  Passport No      Country
1   A5222           India
```

Table_4

```
id  Current Employe      Experience
1     XYZ                   2
```

I need result like below, all tables have common id base on id need the result.

```
id    Name     City     College Name      City    Passport No      Country     Current Employe      Experience
 1    Mazhar   Banglore   R K           Banglore    A5222           India    XYZ                   2
```

If I have more tables in future that also can join extra table also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple join! try this:

```
SELECT Table_1.id,
       Table_1.Name,
       Table_1.City,
       Table_2.[College Name],
       Table_2.City,
       Table_3.[Passport No],
       Table_3.Country,
       Table_4.[Current Employe],
       Table_4.Experience
 FROM Table_1
    INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_2.id = Table_1.id
    INNER JOIN Table_3 ON Table_3.id = Table_1.id
    INNER JOIN Table_4 ON Table_4.id = Table_1.id
```